# Troubleshooting a failed network driver (netvsc.sys)

Tags: networking, hyper-v, drivers, adapter

We have been running into an issue with some terminal servers we have running Server 2016 where the NIC just drops off. These are Hyper-V guests running on 2016 Hyper-V and eventually (after about 2-3 months) the "Microsoft Hyper-V Network Adapter" just fails with "The device cannot start. (Code 10)".

Restarting doesn't make it work and safe mode doesn't make it work. The only way to make it work again is by updating the driver and manually choosing the same driver that is already applied and letting it basically reinstall the same one.

Strange this is this is only happening on a set of VM's that are cloned from a master image using Citrix MCS, but these are also the only VM's that are 24/7 and more heavily used, have folder redirection, etc.

What is the process to try to create some sort of dump like a process dump to try to see why it failed in the first place with a Code 10? The event logs come up empty and even on the hypervisor we can't find anything relating to this problem.

The driver  version is 10.0.14393.2273 which our other VM's don't have an issue with even on the same hosts. So I'm confident that this is related to the VMs and not the hypervisor.

[image: NIC Driver Failed]

Comment: Does the Citrix cloning process Sysprep these images?

Comment: Yes, Citrix MCS does sysprep them and then it creates the virtual machines with the first disk pointing to the parent (read only) and a differencing disk for writes. So each server we deploy from this image with Citrix MCS gets joined to the domain with a unique computer name.

Comment: That sounds... weird. How could it Sysprep the machine and yet use the parent disk of the VM? Can you confirm that the NIC in each VM is unique?

Comment: I guess you bring up a good point lol. Let me look up what exactly it is doing.

Comment: I can't find documentation on it but I know it creates a full copy and puts it on each defined storage, then adds the machines to Active Directory, and creates an "identity" disk for the VM. I'm trying to find out exactly what the identity disk is. I know during the first boot up after provisioning it appears to be doing a sysprep because it is going through the "preparing devices" and all that before it fully boots.

Comment: OK, it does sound like it is doing a Sysprep. I would try to confirm that the NIC in each VM is indeed unique.

Comment: They contain unique hardware ID's (second line), first line under hardware id's and matching device id is the same and of course the MAC addresses are different. Not sure what else to check to identify they are unique.